# Difference between Symbol and Node in TypeScript Compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Can somebody provide a clear definition of what are Symbol and Node in TypeScript compiler API, when and how they are used by compiler and common usage examples by API users.

Also good to know when object contains `.symbol` and when `.aliasSymbol` why and what's difference. (The reason I ask is because sometimes I find what I need in `.aliasSymbol` and sometimes just in `.symbol`. I would like to understand when compiler decides to use which in a short examples if possible.)

Answer (score 10):

`Node`s are part of the Abstract Syntax Tree; these are purely *syntactic* constructs based on the text in compiled files without any attempt to layer type information on top.

`Symbol`s are where the TS compiler has started to lay some more *semantic* constructs on top and you're starting to get type information.

If you have a `TypeChecker` in your hand you can jump from the AST world to the types/symbols world via `checker.getTypeAtLocation(node)`.

There's some more helpful information on the 'TypeScript Deep Dive' web site about this: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/overview

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it clears a lot! Could you also please elaborate on what are `Type`s? I'm currently trying to recursively print function argument types to json with `ts.Type.properties`, `ts.TypeChecker.getDeclaredTypeOfSymbol` and `ts.TypeChecker.typeToString`, but object `{ value : number, str : string }` gets printed as `{value : any, str : any}`. What's the proper way to recursively iterate over types (not nodes)?

Comment: It _can_ get a bit funky in there. If you just want to print a type you could use the TS compiler printer:  `ts.createPrinter();  printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, parameterNode.type!, sourceFile)`.  That'll output the type perfectly, as you described it.